# Does an HTTPS connection to Windows Azure web role stay connected?

Tags: azure, https

It's my understanding that if I connect to a windows Azure web role with HTTPS that there is an initial handshake to exchange certificates and then another connection is made to get data.

Can someone explain to me is the connection persisted or if the user needs another page a few minutes later would there me another exchange of handshakes?  How about if the WebRole was serving data from the Web API, would that be the same?

Comment: no. https is a single connection. the underlying tcp connection is established, the SSL libraries do their handshake, and then data flows on the SAME connection. another https connection will re-do the entire handshakes sequence. If the connection is closed, then the entire handshake is re-done when the next connection gets established.

Comment: So can I ask. When the initial index page is being served in my application then that pages requests multiple scripts and those scripts (AngularJS) fire off multiple HTTP(?) requests. Would there be handshakes for everything followed by the sending of data?

Comment: depends on too many factors. an http/https connection CAN handle multiple requests, **IF** the client and server both support it. but generaly speaking, you should assume that every resource on a page, including the page itself, will use a separate independent http request to fetch that resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on a client capabilities but in terms of modern web browsers I wouldn't be so worried about single connection(handshake) per request:

**HTTP 1.1 - Persistent connection**

Modern browsers use HTTP 1.1 by default which according to [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8.1.2) makes connection persistent by default. Another important aspect of HTTP 1.1 is that it forces support of [HTTP pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) which means that multiple requests to the same endpoint will be send in a batch and response will be also received in a batch (on the same connection). Browsers generally have a limit of connections per server (Chrome - 2 connections by default) and reuse connections.

Azure: [It looks like Azure will drop connection if idle for 4 minutes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2014/02/14/connection-timeout-for-windows-azure-cloud-service-roles-web-worker.aspx)

**Handshake**

Every first connection requires full handshake but subsequent can reuse session ticket (ID), but this depends on a client. Microsoft introduced *TLS session resumption*  some time ago -  [What's New in TLS/SSL (Schannel SSP) in Windows Server and Windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831771.aspx). As long as you have only one host serving HTTPS connection it should resume sessions, according to [this blog post](http://www.dotnetnoob.com/2013/10/hardening-windows-server-20082012-and.html):

> There’s also a warning about session resumption. This is due to the
> Azure load balancer and non-sticky sessions. If you run a single
> instance in your cloud service, session resumption will turn green
> since all connections will hit the same instance.

It should not make any difference if it's a WebAPI or Website. You can always test it using [SSLyze](https://github.com/iSECPartners/sslyze).

Comment: Note that as of November 2014 the Azure public Load Balancing infrastructure supports session affinity: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/30/azure-load-balancer-new-distribution-mode/